# Resource distribution w.r.t. individual capacity - is it a Knapsack problem?

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

I have a problem as follows:

1. I have few office locations and resources with different capabilities (integer numbers).
2. I want to distribute all the resources to different office locations to find the best way to divide them almost equally among the locations so that the capabilities of all the office locations are balanced as much as possible. Couple of things to keep in mind:

• Difference between number of resources in each office location should not be more than one.
• The capability of each office location (reached by adding individual capability) should be nearly equal as possible to each other.

I have researched over the internet and came to know about Knapsack algorithm and Bin-pack algorithm which sounds close to this problem.

Example:
Number of office locations = 3;
Number of people = 8;
People capability = 10, 20, 5, 150, 90, 200, 250, 140 (capabilities values of the 8 resources);

The above numbers are just sample. It can grow to 1000+ for resources and respective capabilities value. Number of office locations can be varied too.

I didn't start the programming part unless I am sure that the path that I am going to take it correct. I am requesting your help to guide me to a correct direction to solve this.

Also, if you can share a probable pseudo code for this, will be a great help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the knapsack problem or is at least as difficult (consider an instance where there are only two offices), so obtaining the best solution will be very difficult. You may try to use some generic optimization heuristic like simulated annealing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing